# unknown type name 'ETSTimer'

Tags: c, ubuntu-16.04, esp8266

i've got this error always when i'm using the below code ,
so please could anyone tell me where is my mistake??

the code is:

```
#ifndef OSAPI_H
#define OSAPI_H

void sdk_os_timer_setfn(ETSTimer *ptimer, ETSTimerFunc *pfunction, void *parg);
void sdk_os_timer_arm(ETSTimer *ptimer, uint32_t milliseconds, bool repeat_flag);
void sdk_os_timer_disarm(ETSTimer *ptimer);

#endif
```

errors i've got:

> 1- :4:25: error: unknown type name 'ETSTimer' 2- :4:43: error: unknown
>   type name 'ETSTimerFunc' 3- :5:23: error: unknown type name 'ETSTimer'
>   4- :6:26: error: unknown type name 'ETSTimer'

thanks for everyone for the help

Comment: So, apparently you are missing some includes which are defining these types.

Comment: Add `#include "os_type.h"` as the third line.

Comment: #include "os_type.h" has been added but error still the same